# JQUERY AJAX and SELECT ELEMENT on JSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, select

Here is my question. I have ajax call which gives one of the value that i need to display on the select field of JSP page and remaining values that i added to model object.

Here is the snippet. if anyone one helps that would be great.

JSP:-

```
 <select class="form-control  mb-6 mr-sm-2" name="parRole" required id="inputSuccess3" style="width:225px;">

    <c:forEach var="role" items="${allParRolesList}">
      <option  value="${role.roleId}" >${role.roleName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
     </select>
```

JQUERY-AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"text",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url:url,
    data: "",
    success:function(data){ 
    console.log(data);
     $('[name="parRole"] option').filter(function(){
     this.value==dataout.parRole.roleId
    }).prop('selected',true);

  }
```

Controller:

```
public @ResponseBody  ParMaster getParDetails(@PathVariable("parNo") String parNo,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView modelView  = new ModelAndView();
    modelView.addObject("allParRolesList", parRoleServiceImpl.getActiveParRoles());
    modelView.setViewName("paredit");
    return pareditserviceImpl.getParDetails(parNo);
}
```

Comment: ok, you have an Ajax call that do stuff, so... what's your question?

Comment: in your filter function you have to return the boolean then only it will filter the options.
instead of using filter you can use jquery val() method like  `$('[name='parRole']").val(dataout.parRole.roleId)`

Comment: Thanks Jerin and Jholman. I figured it out.